# Python (Imaging library): Resample string as argument

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Python beginner question. Code below should explain my problem:

```
import Image

resolution = (200,500)
scaler = "Image.ANTIALIAS"

im = Image.open("/home/user/Photos/DSC00320.JPG")

im.resize(resolution , scaler)
```

RESULT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1255, in resize
    raise ValueError("unknown resampling filter")
ValueError: unknown resampling filter
```

This one works:

```
im.resize(resolution , Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

Answer (score 8):

Well, then Image.ANTIALIAS is not a string, so don't treat it as one:

```
scaler = Image.ANTIALIAS
```

Answer (score 4):

As @ThibThib said using "Image.ANTIALIAS" is not the same thing as Image.ANTIALIAS.
But if you always expect to get the resample value as a string you could do the following:

```
scaler = 'ANTIALIAS'
resample = {
    'ANTIALIAS': Image.ANTIALIAS,
    'BILINEAR': Image.BILINEAR,
    'BICUBIC': Image.BICUBIC
}

im.resize(resolution , resample[scaler])
```

Comment: Or, perhaps:

`im.resize(resolution, getattr(Image, scaler))`

Answer (score 3):

As you said, `im.resize(resolution , Image.ANTIALIAS)` is the solution

You have to take care than this is different than `im.resize(resolution , "Image.ANTIALIAS")`.

In your example, the variable `scaler` has the string `"Image.ANTIALIAS"` as a value, that is different than the value `Image.ANTIALIAS`.

A string representing *xxxx* **is different** than the value *xxxx*, exactly as the string `"12"` is completely different than the integer `12`.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm resurrecting an old question, but to help with anyone dealing with something close to this in modern day.

**Pillow NO LONGER supports the ANTIALIAS filter.**

The solutions above (while correct for the versions of PIL and Pillow in 2009), will still result in a `ValueError: unknown resampling filter` for current versions of Pillow.